# How do I plot a vector field within an arbitrary plane using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, vector, 3d

I have a 3d velocity vector field in a numpy array of shape (zlength, ylength, xlength, 3). The '3' contains the velocity components (u,v,w).

I can quite easily plot the vector field in the orthogonal x-y, x-z, and y-z planes using quiver, e.g.

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xvalues, yvalues)

xyfieldfig = plt.figure()
xyfieldax = xyfieldfig.add_subplot(111)
Q1 = xyfieldax.quiver(X, Y, velocity_field[zslice,:,:,0], velocity_field[zslice,:,:,1])
```

However, I'd like to be able to view the velocity field within an arbitrary plane.

I tried to project the velocity field onto a plane by doing:

```
projected_field = np.zeros(zlength,ylength,xlength,3)
normal = (nx,ny,nz) #normalised normal to the plane

for i in range(zlength):
    for j in range(ylength):
        for k in range(xlength):
            projected_field[i,j,m] = velocity_field[i,j,m] - np.dot(velocity_field[i,j,m], normal)*normal
```

However, this (of course) still leaves me with a 3d numpy array with the same shape: (zlength, ylength, xlength, 3). The projected_field now contains velocity vectors at each (x,y,z) position that lie within planes at each local (x,y,z) position.

How do I project velocity_field onto a single plane? Or, how do I now plot my projected_field along one plane?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll want to create a regular grid in your plane, and use 3 calls to  [`scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html) to interpolate `u,v,w` onto your new grid.

Answer (score 2):

You're close. Daniel F's suggestion was right, you just need to know how to do the interpolation. Here's a worked example

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate  


def norm(v,axis=0):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(v**2,axis=axis))

#Original velocity field
xpoints = np.arange(-.2, .21, 0.05)
ypoints = np.arange(-.2, .21, 0.05)
zpoints = np.arange(-.2, .21, 0.05)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(xpoints,ypoints,zpoints,indexing='ij')

#Simple example
#(u,v,w) are the components of your velocity field
u = x
v = y
w = z 

#Setup a template for the projection plane. z-axis will be rotated to point
#along the plane normal
planex, planey, planez  =
    np.meshgrid(np.arange(-.2,.2001,.1), 
                 np.arange(-.2,.2001,.1), [0.1], 
                 indexing='ij')

planeNormal = np.array([0.1,0.4,.4])
planeNormal /= norm(planeNormal)

#pick an arbirtrary vector for projection x-axis
u0 = np.array([-(planeNormal[2] + planeNormal[1])/planeNormal[0], 1, 1])
u1 = -np.cross(planeNormal,u0) 
u0 /= norm(u0)
u1 /= norm(u1)

#rotation matrix
rotation = np.array([u0,u1,planeNormal]).T


#Rotate plane to get projection vertices
rotatedVertices = rotation.dot( np.array( [planex.flatten(), planey.flatten(), planez.flatten()]) ).T


#Now you can interpolate gridded vector field to rotated vertices
uprime = scipy.interpolate.interpn( (xpoints,ypoints,zpoints), u, rotatedVertices, bounds_error=False )
vprime = scipy.interpolate.interpn( (xpoints,ypoints,zpoints), v, rotatedVertices, bounds_error=False )
wprime = scipy.interpolate.interpn( (xpoints,ypoints,zpoints), w, rotatedVertices, bounds_error=False )

#Projections
cosineMagnitudes = planeNormal.dot( np.array([uprime,vprime,wprime]) )

uProjected = uprime - planeNormal[0]*cosineMagnitudes
vProjected = vprime - planeNormal[1]*cosineMagnitudes
wProjected = wprime - planeNormal[2]*cosineMagnitudes
```

The number of lines could be reduced using some `tensordot` operations if you wanted to get fancy. Also this or some close variant it would work without `indexing='ij'` in `meshgrid`.

Original field:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1, normalize=True)
```

[image: original]

Projected field:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.quiver(rotatedVertices[:,0], rotatedVertices[:,1], rotatedVertices[:,2], 
          uprime, vprime,wprime, length=0.5, color='blue', label='Interpolation only')
ax.quiver(rotatedVertices[:,0], rotatedVertices[:,1], rotatedVertices[:,2], 
          uProjected, vProjected, wProjected, length=0.5, color='red', label='Interpolation + Projection')


plt.legend()
```

[image: projected]